# Newsletter scheduled but not sending: 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, newsletter

I can't find any google solution that matches my problem.

- Cron is working.
- Order e-mails are sent with success.
- All other e-mails are working too, excepting newsletter.

My last newsletter was sent using 1.7.0.2.
But after updates to 1.9.1.0 my newsletter e-mails are not being sent.

Cron schedule table shows up all queues, including `newsletter_send_all` with success message.
Going to backend I can see ZERO `processed` from thousands of subscribers.
No newsletter e-mail was sent.
No errors in Magento logs, PHP logs and Apache logs.

What could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this extension : https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension
(You can see all logs of sending emails and configure other mail server is if needed)

and this extension: https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler (You can check the cron and review when scheduled, etc).

Comment: I am facing same issue in magento 1.8.1.0 and confirm your answer that cron is working and other transnational email are working but still newsletter showing `not sent` and not any newsletter email